# where did sidekiq process run?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

Suppose that I have a Rais app with sidekiq running on IP 10.0.0.1, and just pointed the redis on sidekiq to the IP 10.0.0.2, like this

```
redisServer = "10.0.0.2"
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => 'redis://' + redisServer + ':6379/0' }
end
```

What machine will process the background jobs?

Comment: the machine where sidekiq runs?

Comment: Yea, I'm reading my question again. Doesn't make much sense...But is there a way to have a dedicated machine?

Comment: You can have a dedicated machine running only sidekiq jobs. Your `10.0.0.1` would be this machine since you can share data through `redis`.

Comment: How can I do this? Should I have my app deployed to another machine with something like `foreman` running only the `sidekiq` command? I don't know if I made myself clear enough

Comment: Sounds like a good start. Experiment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sidekiq is running on IP 10.0.0.1, then that's where your jobs will be processed.

redis is just a key-value store. That doesn't process your jobs